# Why proc fiesystem is empty if mounted over NFS

Tags: linux, nfs, proc

I was curious to see if I could display contents of /proc virtual filesystem which was mounted over network. So I exported "/" and mounted it in another system over NFS. Then I did cd in to proc directory and did ls. It displayed nothing. Someone please explain why it is empty.

Comment: `/proc` is not supposed to be used that way, in particular because pseudo-files inside are expected to be read sequentially and don't give any meaningful size.

Answer (score 1):

Please read `man 5 exports`:

```
   nohide This option is based on the option of the same name provided  in
          IRIX  NFS.  Normally, if a server exports two filesystems one of
          which is mounted on the other, then  the  client  will  have  to
          mount  both filesystems explicitly to get access to them.  If it
          just mounts the parent, it will see an empty  directory  at  the
          place where the other filesystem is mounted.  That filesystem is
          "hidden".
```

By default the client doesn't see nested mounts.